# Swift 3.0 and web service

Tags: ios, json, swift

Attempting to read our web service into a UITableViewController and it only returns the first record to the simulator.  So hoping that someone will be able to look at the code and guide me down the correct path. Ultimate goal is to get it into a UITableViewCell so I can format nicely but just looking to get all the records.

Here is a view of the partial json file that will be returned.

```
{
"Count":11518,
"Result":[
    {
     "cuName": "#1",
     "charter_Num": 
     "16328","City": 
     "Jonesboro",
     "State_id": "GA",
     "cuName_location": "#1 - Jonesboro, GA"
     },
     {
     "cuName": "@lantec Financial",
     "charter_Num": "7965",
     "City": "Virginia Beach",
     "State_id": "VA",
     "cuName_location": "@lantec Financial - Virginia Beach, VA"
     }]
}
```

Here is the code that reads in the json web service and attempts to parse and put in the table.

```
func get_data_from_url(_ link:String)
   {
    let url:URL = URL(string: link)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData


    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
             return
        }


        self.extract_json(data!)
    })

    task.resume()
}


func extract_json(_ data: Data)
{
    let json: Any?

    do
    {
        json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    }
    catch
    {
        return
    }

    //Commented out the following lines because it doesn't return anything when using the modified code that works
    //
    //        guard let data_list = json as? NSArray else
    //        {
    //            return
    //        }

    //This code works but only gives me the 1st record back
    if let cu_list = try? json as? [String:Any],
        let result = cu_list?["Result"] as? [[String:Any]],
        let charter_num = result[0]["charter_Num"] as? String,
        let value = result[0]["cuName_location"] as? String, result.count > 0 {
        TableData.append(value + " (" + charter_num + ")")
    } else {
        print("bad json - do some recovery")
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {self.do_table_refresh()})

}
```

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Do not use `snake_case` for method and variable names in Swift. Instead you should be using lower `camelCase`. (2) If the type can be easily inferred, you do not need to specify the type. (3) Curly brackets should be inline with the statement or declaration, not placed on a new line. (4) `!` force unwraps an optional. This should be used judiciously, as if you try to force unwrap an optional that has a `nil` value, your app will crash at runtime.

Comment: @EricAya, thank you for that information.  I am a beginner Swift developer so I was attempting to get something to work and found that site.

Comment: @RyanH. great feedback on improvements that I can make to my code to have it read better and hopefully respond better.  Thank you

Comment: @EricAya Do you have a recommendation for a tutorial on how I can read a json file into a UITableViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring the 0th index element from `result` object and it will only return the 1st record from JSON data. You need to run thru the loop and append the data to array which you need to use for populating the data in `UITableView`.

Comment: Gurdev, what you said makes sense I am unfamiliar with what I need to change to make it work. Can you offer a coding example of how to fix it?  I am in the beginning phase of trying to figure out swift programming.

Comment: try this `if let result = cu_list?["Result"] as? [[String:Any]] {
 var i=0;
 for (i=0;i<result.count;i++) {

  let charter_num = result[i]["charter_Num"] as? String
  let value = result[0]["cuName_location"] as? String
  TableData.append(value + " (" + charter_num + ")")

    }

}`

Answer (score -1):

```
 func GetCategoryData(){
    //get_high_score.php?from=1472409001482&number=10&to=1493657787867
    let checklaun = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Language")
     if checklaun == 1 {

        EZLoadingActivity.show("Loading...", disableUI: false)

    }else{
       EZLoadingActivity.show("جار التحميل...", disableUI: false)

    }


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        let myUrl = URL(string: GlobleUrl.BASEURL + "advertise_list.php");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        // let fromvalue = 1472409001482
        // let numbervalue = 10
        // let tovalue = 1493657787867
        let postString = ""//"from=" + fromvalue + "&" + "number=" + numbervalue + "&" + "to=" + tovalue

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                EZLoadingActivity.hide(false, animated: true)
                print("error=\(error)")
                let checklaun = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Language")
                var titlemsga : String = String()
                var okmsg : String = String()
                if checklaun == 1 {
                    titlemsga = "Something going wrong"
                    okmsg = "Ok"
                }else{
                    titlemsga = "حدث خطأ ما"
                    okmsg = "حسنا"
                }

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: titlemsga, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: okmsg, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                return
            }


            print("response = \(response)")


            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if let parseJSON = json {

                        print(parseJSON)
                        let status =   parseJSON["status"] as! Bool

                        if status == true{

                            EZLoadingActivity.hide(true, animated: false)

                            self.categoryDataArray =  parseJSON["data"] as! NSMutableArray
                            print("\(self.categoryDataArray)")

                            self.filterarray = parseJSON["fixed_cat"] as! NSMutableArray

                            let teamp = self.categoryDataArray .value(forKey: "main_image") as AnyObject
                            print("\(teamp)")
                            self.categoryImageArray.setArray(teamp as! [Any])
                            print("\( self.categoryImageArray)")

                            //  let teamp = self.data .value(forKey: "name") as AnyObject
                            // print("\(teamp)")
                            //  self.categoryNameArray.setArray(teamp as! [Any])


                            self.allcategoryTableViewCell.reloadData()
                            self.allcategoryfilterlistview.reloadData()
                            //   self.tblscoreList.reloadData()

                        }else{
                            EZLoadingActivity.hide(false, animated: true)
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                EZLoadingActivity.hide(false, animated: true)
                let checklaun = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Language")
                var titlemsga : String = String()
                var okmsg : String = String()
                if checklaun == 1 {
                    titlemsga = "Something going wrong"
                    okmsg = "Ok"
                }else{
                    titlemsga = "حدث خطأ ما"
                    okmsg = "حسنا"
                }

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: titlemsga, preferredStyle:     UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: okmsg, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```